# How do we resolve the issue that vi suddenly does not work?

Tags: vim

for some reason my vim suddenly does not work:

```
$ vi
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fff77f3b000 (most recent call first):

Vim: Caught deadly signal ABRT
Vim: Finished.
Abort trap: 6

$ vim
Error detected while processing /Users/myname/.vimrc:
line    6:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'default'
line   26:
E484: Can't open file AAAAA/syntax/syntax.vim
line  182:
E484: Can't open file AAAAA/syntax/syntax.vim
line  306:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'default'ImportError: No module named site
```

I do not know what is happening and actually I do not care. I just want to reset everything with conda by reinstall everything necessary? is it possible? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to delete the `.vimrc` file and create a new one, then try to use `vim`:

```
$ rm ~/.vimrc
$ touch ~/.vimrc
$ vim
```

that should reset the basic configuration file and might solve your issue.

In addition you can try to delete the `.vim` folder:

```
$ rm -r ~/.vim
```

(for both options it is recommended to backup before you delete)

Comment: You can also just use `vim -u NONE`.